# Websockets client support in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, websocket, windows-phone-8

When I read about [MessageWebSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR226842) class in Windows 8, I started to think about an Application which could use that client in the Windows Phone 8.

But, digging deeper I've just figured out that class is not in the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Do you know if is there any other implementation of a Websockets client which is compatible with Windows Phone 8?. (Behold, not Windows 8)

Answer (score 4):

Windows Phone 8 unfortunately provides no native websocket-support like WinRT's MessageWebSocket. You can use the websocket4net library (see codeplex: http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/) for your wp8 app.

EDIT: websocket4net also supports SSL for WP8!

regards, alex

Comment: SSL support is now available for wp8 websockets (websocket4net).

Comment: could you give out the proof ?

Comment: We use the ssl websockets in our windows phone 8 app "pharao.cloud". see: http://www.windowsphone.com/de-at/store/app/pharao-cloud/50c90ae3-2aef-4353-81e3-fa18c1b4b0be

Answer (score 1):

I'd give a try to SignalR... it seems the right way to implement WebSockets since it's part of the MSFT Web tech stack: [Channel 9 intro video](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Building-real-time-connected-apps-with-Windows-Phone-8-and-SignalR)

BTW: the API has an interesting level of abstraction where you can manage client groups, nice support for different authentication startegies, etc... The only think I miss is that binary serialization is not supported, at least out of the box.